# FluorineFX C# sample to call a remote function through RTMP

Tags: c#, rtmp, fluorinefx

I am seeking a sample to call a remote function through RTMP protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind,I found it..

http://www.fluorinefx.com/docs/fluorine/netconnectionrtmp.html

Comment: Did you get this to work? The docs have tutorials for VS2003, and I'm using VS2012. I couldn't find the options that the install documentation had.